# how to rollback changes for an update query in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I made a query in mongodb for updating a document in a collection that include adding additional fields in that document.
Then i made another to update another document in another collection and executed in the result function of first query,but i got error while updating the second one.
I need to roll back changes made on the 1 st document.
please help

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/transactions.html) you can rollback a transaction in mongoose using `session.abortTransaction()`

**Sample code from docs**

```
let session = null;
return Customer.createCollection().
  then(() => Customer.startSession()).
  then(_session => {
    session = _session;
    session.startTransaction();
    return Customer.create([{ name: 'Test' }], { session: session });
  }).
  then(() => Customer.create([{ name: 'Test2' }], { session: session })).
  then(() => session.abortTransaction()).
  then(() => Customer.countDocuments()).
  then(count => assert.strictEqual(count, 0));
```